# Could not create lock at /var/run/yum.pid

Tags: yum

On CentOS, when I try to use `yum`, I keep getting:

```
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Could not create lock at /var/run/yum.pid: [Errno 28] No space left on device: '/var/run/yum.pid' 
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  19 M RSS (301 MB VSZ)
    Started: Tue Aug 27 14:27:41 2013 - 00:00 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 21381
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  19 M RSS (301 MB VSZ)
    Started: Tue Aug 27 14:27:41 2013 - 00:02 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 21381
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  19 M RSS (301 MB VSZ)
    Started: Tue Aug 27 14:27:41 2013 - 00:04 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 21381
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: yum
    Memory :  19 M RSS (301 MB VSZ)
    Started: Tue Aug 27 14:27:41 2013 - 00:06 ago
    State  : Running, pid: 21381
```

My disk space is definitely more than enough. The `/var/run/yum.pid` file is also missing.

How can I fix `yum`?

Comment: You're running this command via `sudo`?

Comment: I have a similar issue, but /run (a tmpfs FS) is full....

Answer (score 1):

Can you check what's the process with PID 21381?

```
ps -p 21381
```

I would guess you are working from a GUI where a package manager/updater is started automatically and which is currently trying to fetch some updates. Or there may be a cron batch which runs some yum commands periodically. Btw, what distribution is installed on your system?

The easiest way would be to kill that process but firstly verify what it is.

Comment: CentOs 6.1
ps -fea | grep yum
root     16191 15756  0 13:09 pts/0    00:00:00 grep yum

Answer (score 1):

I can't upvote the last answer but actually showed me my problem.

```
[root@db ~]# df -i
Filesystem     Inodes IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       1.9M  1.9M     0  100% /
tmpfs            921K     6  921K    1% /dev/shm

[root@db ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       30G   18G   11G  65% /
tmpfs           3.6G   20K  3.6G   1% /dev/shm
```

I'll link to another question that suggests how to [free up inodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653096/howto-free-inode-usage).

I logged off any users that were just logged in and then deleting everything in /tmp.  That moved the inodes from 100% to 52%.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens, `yum` process is already being ran in the background and a lock file `/var/run/yum.pid` is created. At this point (if you wanted to terminate yum )  you would send a `SIGTERM` to the `yum` process. This is `kill -s 15 $(pgrep yum)`. The other option is to let `yum` finish it's processing before you run it manually.

Answer (score -1):

please check the inode status by below command.

```
df -i
```

free some inode by removing some files.